# Why won't Lightroom let me export with different settings?

Tags: lightroom, export

I have no idea what happened but my Lightroom stopped exporting. I can open the export window but I can not click any of the settings like size, watermarks, etc. The only thing I can do is to choose the folder where I want to export to.

I have just exported the same images with watermarks and wanted to export them in a different size, but nothing works anymore. Anybody an idea how to fix that?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot? Depending on version, you may have a dropdown at the top, make sure that is set to 'Hard Drive'

Comment: Has it ever worked? Have you changed preferences at all?

Comment: If you are using the online "cloud" version of LR, have you checked to see if your subscription is up-to-date?

Comment: @marcellothearcane it worked well for 2 years so far, and I don't remember changing any preferences

Comment: @laurencemadill The dropdown was set to harddrive, but now I cant even select images anymore so I can't send a screenshot of the export window either. Seems like everything is stopping working. The version I have is local on my laptop, Lightroom 5.7 if that helps?

Comment: @Michael Clark I am using the local version on my laptop, Lightroom 5.7. Does it help anyhow? I ran updates on my laptop already but nothing seems to help

Comment: @aneta was it a trial of Lightroom which has subsequently expired?